# How to fetch values of keys from one column to another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Suppose I have an excel sheet with following format:

| City Code | City1 | City2 | TaxCode of City2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | NewYork | Kathmandu | 48 |
| 20 | Mumbai | NewYork | 60 |
| 12 | Ireland | Mumbai | 25 |
| 61 | Paris | Kathmandu | 48 |

We want to obtain a table having the following columns which has mapping of Tax Code for city1 as well in the last column, how can we achieve this for all the rows in excel.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

| City Code | City1 | City2 | TaxCode of City2 | TaxCode of City1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | New York | Kathmandu | 48 | 60 |
| 20 | Mumbai | NewYork | 60 | 25 |
| 12 | Ireland | Mumbai | 25 | 43 |
| 61 | Paris | Kathmandu | 48 | 53 |

Comment: `XLOOKUP()` or `VLOOKUP()` will do

Comment: we want to do it for entire table having 100+ rows, any formula that we can use it? @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Yes, apply either of the above functions in the adjacent column please. Try : `=XLOOKUP(B2:B5,C2:C5,D2:D5)`

Comment: Ok, is it a typo that in `City1` --> `New York` has a space in between while in `City2` it doesn't. If thats typo then try this as well: `=VLOOKUP(B2:B5,C2:D5,2,0)`

Comment: Or this `=LET(α,A2:D5,
HSTACK(α,XLOOKUP(INDEX(α,,2),INDEX(α,,3),INDEX(α,,4))))`